# ng-Repeat on stacked up cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have three cards aligned on top of each other by using z-index. I am trying to find a way i can replicate the cards by using ng -Repeat so it looks like this

First         Second 
Stack         Stack
of 3 Cards      of 3 Cards

```css
  #edit_card{
        position: absolute;
        z-index:-150;
        width:340px;
        height:450px;
       background-color:ghostwhite;
    }
    #learn_more
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:-100;
        width:340px;
        height:450px;
        background-color:ghostwhite;
    }
    #main_card
    {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:50;
        width:340px;
        height:450px;
        background-color:ghostwhite;
    }
```

```html
<div class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap   >


    <md-card id="edit_card" >
                <md-card-content ng-class="" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                     <img src="" width="45px" height="45px" class="md-card-image" alt="image caption">
                    <div class="edit_block" layout="row" layout-align="center" style="width:100%;height:30%;margin-bottom:2.75%;">
                        <md-button></md-button>
                    </div>
                     <img src="" width="45px" height="45px" class="md-card-image" alt="image caption">
                    <div class="edit_block" layout="row" layout-align="center"  style="width:100%;height:30%;margin-bottom:2.75%;">
                        <md-button>Edit Application</md-button>
                    </div>
                     <img src="" width="45px" height="45px" class="md-card-image" alt="image caption">
                    <div class="edit_block" layout="row" layout-align="center" style="width:100%;height:30%;margin-bottom:2.75%;">
                        <md-button>Learn More</md-button>
                    </div>

                </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
    <md-card id="learn_more" >
                <md-card-content ng-class="" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                   Learn More Card
                </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
    <md-card id="main_card" >
                <md-card-content ng-class="" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                   <button ng-click="changeZ()">Change Z</button>
                </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
       
        </div>
```

If any one has any ideas on how i can use ng-Repeat here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How you would use ng-repeat would be dependent upon your controller, what data you want to display in the cards and how that data is accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat iterates over an array, so you should first build a data model/object that holds all of the card information you would like to display. Additionally you may add all of your css styles to the object as well.

Sample object:

```
{ 
    name:"edit_card",
    content: [
        {
            buttonText: "Edit Application",
            style: {
                width: "100%",
                height: "30%",
                "margin-bottom": "2.75%"
            }
        },
        {
            buttonText: "Learn More",
            style: {
                width: "100%",
                height: "30%",
                "margin-bottom": "2.75%"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So you will have an object like this for each of your cards and you will assemble them into an array like so...

```
$scope.arrayOfCards = [
    { name: "edit_card" ... },
    { name: "learn_more" ... },
    { name: "main_card" ... }
];
```

Then to implement the ng-repeat it would look something like this:

```
<div class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap >
    <md-card ng-repeat="card in arrayOfCards" id="{{card.name}}">
        <md-card-content ng-class="" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        // optionally you can iterate through the content array from the example above I created.
            <div ng-repeat="content in card">
                <img src="" width="45px" height="45px" class="md-card-image" alt="image caption">
                <div class="edit_block" layout="row" layout-align="center" ng-style="content.style">
                <md-button>{{content.buttonText}}</md-button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: @RaghavaManvithaReddy No problem.